# Twitter Streaming API: Can we use the coordinates inside 'place' element as an alternative to coordinates in the 'coordinates' element at upper level?

Tags: twitter

I have got data downloaded using Twit Streaming API. Some percentage of tweets have **coordinates{coordinates}** values while some have NULL values (and I know why). On the other hand, the **place{coordinates}** values are all Non-NULL in the form of four lon/lat pairs specifying a bounding box.

1-Can I compute the centroid of these bounding-boxes in order to replace the NULL values of **coordinates{coordinates}**? Is it correct way of mapping such tweets to a precise location?

2-For some tweets, the **coordinates{coordinates}** values belong to one country, but the **place{coordinates}** values for the same tweet specify a different country altogether. Why is it so?

thanks